# Big gap between navigation bar and image view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I want to have an image attached to the navigation bar in the top, and I've set the constraint for aligning the top to the Safe Area. However, I'm still getting a gap between the navigation bar and the image.

This is the imageView in the storyboard:

```xml
<imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RhX-yV-z6m">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="59" width="393" height="300"/>
    <constraints>
        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="300" id="hHl-BI-vaA"/>
    </constraints>
</imageView>
...
<constraints>
    <constraint firstItem="RhX-yV-z6m" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="top" id="Cmp-yp-bTm"/>
    <constraint firstItem="RhX-yV-z6m" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="leading" id="FRF-Ih-As7"/>
    <constraint firstItem="vDu-zF-Fre" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="RhX-yV-z6m" secondAttribute="trailing" id="MHN-QC-Qzh"/>
    <constraint firstItem="s0c-di-Frp" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="RhX-yV-z6m" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="50" id="qEO-41-GBJ"/>
...
</constraints>
```

And this is how it's shown:
[image]

All I have done to the image in the swift code is use `UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill`.

Is there anything I can do to have the image attached to the top bar without having to set a negative constraint?

Comment: Is the image view added directly to the view controller’s view or some other sub view?

Comment: There is a `constant="50"` in there. Does it have anything to do with it? Anyway, what you seem to be trying to do should be pretty simple. There are some options though like pinning it to either safe area or the view itself. Also to use margin or not. You should be able to find all of those by selecting a constrain and modifying it.

Comment: The frame rect has y=59.

Comment: @PtitXav I have removed it and nothing has changed.

Comment: @HangarRash The image view is directly in the view controller, but I've just tried moving it to another sub view and it looked the same.

Comment: @MaticOblak That constant is for another element below the image view. How can I pin it to the safe area?
I have tried modifying the margins, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you a warning in IB, because you have 2 Y positions for the image :y=59 and same top as safe area ?

Comment: @PtitXav I don't have any warnings